# Selenium: Testing custom form elements

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, tdd, webdriver

Select boxes, checkboxes and radiobuttons are difficult to style with CSS, so it is common to apply plugins, replacing the native form elements with regular elements that are easier to apply CSS to.

The jQuery UI Selectmenu is an example: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

These plugins typically produce markup like this:

```
<select name="mySelect" style="display: none; ">
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><!-- ... -->
</select>
<a class="pretty-select-box">...</a>
<ul class="pretty-select-box-dropdown-list">
    <li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</a></li><!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

The problem is that when such plugins are installed, Selenium tests using the native form elements will fail with this exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

What is the best approach to fix this? I figure this must be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find much information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how to disable the plugin you're using in the web page. However, I can tell you that one of the primary goals of WebDriver is to interact with the page as the user sees it. Therefore, you cannot interact with elements directly that are not visible. You always have the option of using JavaScript to manipulate the element, if you absolutely *have* to interact with the hidden element. Bear in mind, though, that in doing so, you lose one of the main advantages of using WebDriver (especially with so-called "native events"), namely that you don't need to worry about manually triggering events on the elements as the driver does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the website to work (functionally, even if it's not pretty) without the fancy plugins enabled. So maybe disable the plugins and make the testing easier?